# Create "n" SubArrays from an Array with loop

Tags: c#, arrays

I would like to ask how to create a subarray from an array with a loop.

I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

(problem with converting `int[]` to `int`)

```
int[] numere = new int[k];
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    numere[i] = i + 1;
}

string output = string.Join("   ", numere);
label1.Text = output;`

double t = Math.Sqrt(k);
int b = (int)t;

int[] subArr = new int[b];
for (j=0; j < b; j++)
{
    var newrrat = numere.Skip(b).Take(b).ToArray();
    subArr[j] = newrrat; 
    j++;
}
```

I need radical from "k" subArrays. Is this posible?

So for example:

if k=16 I have:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16

I need 4 subArrays:

> 1,2,3,4
>   5,6,7,8
>   9,10,11,12
>   13,14,15,16

Comment: Don't you find any of the provided answers helpful? If you do, mark it as accepted answer by clicking the green mark below the score buttons in that particular answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create your number range easily with

```
var nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 16).ToList();
```

and than use this to get your subranges.

```
var subs = new List<int[]>();
for (int j = 0; j < k; j += b)
    subs.Add(nums.Take(b).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a list instead:

```
        int k = 16;
        int[] numere = new int[k];
        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            numere[i] = i + 1;
        }

        double t = Math.Sqrt(k);
        int b = (int) t;

        List<int[]> subArr = new List<int[]>();
        for (j = 0; j < k; j+=b)
        {
            int[] newrrat = numere.Skip(j).Take(b).ToArray();
            subArr.Add(newrrat);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make `subArr` an array of arrays (or a 2D array, whatever suits you best):

```
int[][] subArr = new int[b][];
```

This is somewhat hard to read, so I tend to prefer using either a custom type or `List` instead:

```
var subArr = new List<int[]>(b);
```

You can then use `subArr.Add(newrrat)`.

Your code also has a mistake - you'll only ever skip `b` numbers, while you probably want to skip `b * j`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    int i, j;
    int k = 16;
    int[] numere = new int[k];
    int b = (int)Math.Sqrt(k);

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) 
        numere[i] = i + 1;

    int[,] subArr = new int[b,b];
    for( i = 0; i < b; i++) 
        for( j = 0; j < b; j++) 
            subArr[i,j] = numere[(i * b) + j];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrays = Enumerable.Range(1, 16).ToArray()
            .GroupBy(i => (Math.Ceiling(i / (double)4)))
            .Select(g => g.ToArray())
            .ToArray();
```